# I need help! Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus

Show that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(a)=P'(a)=0$ then there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that [P(x)=(x-a)^2Q(x).]

I really do not understand where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I have:

$(x-a)F(x)$ for some polynomial $F(x)$.

$P'(x)=2(x-a)Q(x) \cdot Q'(x)$

We can assume that $P(x)=(x-a)F(x).$

$P'(x)=F(x)+F'(x)(x-a)$

$(x-a)F(x)=F(x)+F'(x)(x-a)$

Next, we can insert $a$ to solve for F(a).
$(a-a)F(a)=F(a)+F'(a)(a-a)$

$(0)F(a)=F(a)+F'(a)(0)$

$F(a)=0$

Comment: Want to know why you have downvotes? You haven't explain what you tried or what is confusing, and saying "Quick!" is very off-putting.

Comment: Now then, a hint: Take the derivative symbolically and see what happens. You can easily construct such a $Q$ that satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: OP made an honest attempt to solve the problem and started off correctly, so I do not understand why some are down-voting the question.

Comment: OK, now I see that the downvotes came before OP edited the question in response to the comments from @SeanRoberson. Perhaps with a new contributor, we can give a reasonable opportunity for them to respond to comments before downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

You started off correctly but should have made it more explicit.

Since $P(a)=0$ we know that there is a polynomial $F(x)$ such that
$$ P(x)=(x-a)F(x) $$

Then you correctly conclude that

$$ P^\prime(x)=F(x)+(x-a)F^\prime(x) $$

But we also know that $P^\prime(a)=0$ so that tells us that there is some polynomial $G(x)$ such that

$$ P^\prime(x)=(x-a)G(x) $$

So we have that

$$ F(x)+(x-a)F^\prime(x)=(x-a)G(x) $$

which can be re-written

$$ F(x)=(x-a)(G(x)-F^\prime(x)) $$

Therefore

$$ P(x)=(x-a)F(x)=(x-a)^2(G(x)-F^\prime(x)) $$

Thus the desired $Q(x)=G(x)-F^\prime(x)$

Comment: Or just insert in the second formula $x=a$ to find $0=P'(a)=F(a)$. Then factorize $F(x)=(x-a)G(x)$ directly.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, much better.